# Can doxygen determine the class from the use statements?

Tags: php, class, namespaces, doxygen

I'm trying to document code with doxygen and for classes within my app code the links to other classes work as desired. But if I reference in an @return or @param a class from elsewhere (e.g. vendor....) without the namespace (cos I have the namespace referenced in a "use"). It doesn't find it. Is this expected behaviour (and so I need to prefix the class name with the namespace)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class names should always be fully qualified for your doxygen/docblock return types. This will allow it to create links between classes.